# Unable to get a string out of a method

Tags: c#, string, void

I am really new to coding, never studied it or something similar, just learning it myself, never done it before, but I am trying to create my first real application right new.
However, I have some problems for 2 days which I just can't figure out, so I hope you can help me out.

Alright, so before the youtubedlCurrentWorker_Process() is created, I did define 'public string CurrentYouTubeDLVersion'.
How ever, when a button in my application executes the youtubedlCompareVersion_Process(), the CurrentYouTubeDLVersion string is empty, when it comes at the compare point.
Below is just a little part of my code.

Why is the string CurrentYouTubeDLVersion empty in the CompareVersion while the GetCurrentVersion ran before it?
Even if I double click "CurrentYouTubeDLVersion" in Visual Studio, it won't show a link to the one in the GetCurrentVersion_Process.

```
namespace MediaDownloader
{
public partial class updates : UserControl
    {
        public string LatestYoutubeDLVersion;
        public string CurrentYouTubeDLVersion;

    public void youtubedlGetCurrentVersion_Process()
    {
        if (File.Exists(YouTubeDLPath))
        {
            //Here I get the current version of youtube-dl.exe, to get the version number, we have to run youtube-dl.exe --version
            Process youtubedl = new Process();
            youtubedl.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            youtubedl.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            youtubedl.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            youtubedl.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            youtubedl.StartInfo.FileName = YouTubeDLPath;
            youtubedl.StartInfo.Arguments = " --version";
            youtubedl.Start();
            string CurrentYouTubeDLVersion = youtubedl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                CurrentYouTubeDLVersionText.Text = "Current youtube-dl.exe version: " + CurrentYouTubeDLVersion;
                YouTubeDLVersionStatusText.Text = null;
                UpdateYouTubeDL.IsEnabled = false;
            }));

        }
    public void youtubedlCompareVersion_Process()
    {
        youtubedlGetCurrentVersion_Process();
        string LatestYoutubeDLVersion = WebClient.DownloadString("https://yt-dl.org/latest/version");
        MessageBox.Show("Latest:" + LatestYoutubeDLVersion + "Current " + CurrentYouTubeDLVersion);
        int YouTubeDLUptodate = CurrentYouTubeDLVersion.CompareTo(LatestYoutubeDLVersion);
        if (YouTubeDLUptodate < 1)
        {
            YouTubeDLVersionStatusText.Text = "Your youtube-dl.exe is out of date, please click the button below to update.";
            UpdateYouTubeDL.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            YouTubeDLVersionStatusText.Text = "youtube-dl.exe is up to date!";
            UpdateYouTubeDL.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Grant Winney is right. Remove `string ` before `LatestYoutubeDLVersion` and `CurrentYouTubeDLVersion` in your methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `youtubedlGetCurrentVersion_Process` method, you're creating a new `CurrentYouTubeDLVersion` string, and it's completely separate from the public `CurrentYouTubeDLVersion` you added to the top of the class.

```
string CurrentYouTubeDLVersion = youtubedl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Assign to the class-level variable you made, instead of creating a new `string`:

```
CurrentYouTubeDLVersion = youtubedl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Then the value will be available to you in `youtubedlCompareVersion_Process`.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the 'string' in front of CurrentYouTubeDLVersion and it should work

```
    public youtubedlGetCurrentVersion_Process()
    {
       /* removed code to make easier to read */
       //string CurrentYouTubeDLVersion = youtubedl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
       CurrentYouTubeDLVersion = youtubedl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
       /* removed code to make easier to read */
    }
```